# Dohop's iframe breaks div

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe

I'm trying to add dohop's whitelabel flight search to my site http://dohop.otezz.com/. But the script they provided breaks my header's div. I've trying to add `height: 100%` to the css class but nothing happened.

Adding the iframe manually to the site makes the page show correctly. But if I hit the search button, it doesn't expand as expected.

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the iframe supposed to be in your header? because it is. it's giving the header a 900+ px height.

Comment: Yes it is. I want it to show after the site navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it : 
From your html website output :

```
<div class="header-wrapper home-background clearfix" style="height: 776px;">
```

remove the style `style="height: 776px;` part and let me know if that gives the result you like !

Comment: Nice find! I wasn't able to find that line because the style attribute is added from jQuery function. Now I just commented that function and now it works. Thanks